# WPF or Windows Form

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I have given a new project that is all about automation. I have to automate Windows & Web based applications from a .NET based application i.e. the .NET based application should be able to read controls of the external web application as well as the windows based applications in order to do get and push data.

Kindly advise the .NET based application should be developed on Windows Forms technology or WPF/C#?

Also is there any way to automate Java Applet application from .NET/C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't say I know much about that stuff but it seems to me if it's automation you wouldn't need a UI so I wouldn't use either WPF or Win Forms. If you need a UI and you are familiar with WPF (or have time to learn) you should always use it. Otherwise stick to Win Forms.

Answer (score 6):

WPF is worth to learn. Many of standard UI modificiations which you'd like to do in WinForms will take a loooot of time and in WPF you can do most of them just like that.

WPF has also many useful features, your application will be displayed the same way on each computer, no problems with font DPI etc.

In wpf you can easily add animations, gradients, styles, localization etc.
I strongly recommend that over WinForms. Also WPF force good practices like MVVM pattern, because of which your code will be more flexible, maintainable and readable.

Everything depends on what is your goal and how often do you want to use that technology. If you want to create small application one/twice a year, then there is no reason to learn WPF which is more complex, but if you want to create more projects and learn something once, which  give you great flexibility then you should definitely learn WPF.

Answer (score 4):

WPF and WinForms mostly differs in UI contruction approach. If you don't need UI you can stick to any of them, overwise i'll advice you to use WPF as it is much more flexible and design-friendly than WinForms. Though WinForms is easier to use for basic UI if you don't know WPF, IMHO.